# Continuing script after long command executed over SSH

Tags: bash, ssh, remote-server

My `local` computer is running a bash script that executes another script (locally) on a `remote` like so :

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# do stuff
ssh remote@remote "/home/remote/path/to/script.sh"
echo "Done"
# do other stuff
```

`script.sh` takes around 15 minutes to execute. **Without loss of connection**, `script.sh` is executed completely (until the very last line). Though, **`Done` will never be echoed** (nor will the `other stuff` be executed).

Notes :

- I've experimented using `screen` and `nohup`, but like I said, the connection is stable and `script.sh` is executed thoroughly (`script.sh` doesn't seem to be dropped).
- I need `script.sh` to be over before I can move on to doing `other stuff` so I can't really run the script and detach (or I will need to know when the script is over before I can start doing `other stuff`).
- Everything works fine if I use a dummy script that last only 5 minutes (instead of 15).

Edit :
`script.sh` used for testing :

```sh
#!/bin/bash
touch /tmp/start
echo "Start..." & sleep 900; touch /tmp/endofscript
```

Comment: Are you sure the remote script is really exiting? Try `ssh remote@remote "/home/remote/path/to/script.sh; echo 'Done on remote side.'"` Also, if you run `ssh remote@remote "/home/remote/path/to/script.sh"` manually, does that exit when it's finished?

Comment: I've tried both. 1st one doesn't echo, 2nd one doesn't exit. In both case, the last instruction of the script is executed (`touch /tmp/endofscript`)

Comment: In that case, it's something in the script itself; for some reason it's not actually exiting. Does it have an exit trap or anything like that? Try replacing the script that doesn't do anything except exit immediately, and see if that has the problem. If it doesn't, try removing bits of the real script and see if you can gradually trim everything that *doesn't* case the problem... so whatever's left must be the problem.

Comment: Although not necessary, perhaps add a hard exit in script.sh? Are you sure you are not seeing a previous run /tmp/endofscript ? To make sure delete /tmp/start & /tmp/endofscript at the start. Perhaps also increase debugging in sshd config.

Comment: Does script.sh invoke any processes which are supposed to continue running after script.sh exits?

Comment: @Kenster nope. I've trimmed the scripts down to literally what is posted in the question. Just 2 dumb scripts. I've also changed the remote to a different server to make sure it wasn't specific to my remote configuration.

Comment: @wowbagger Hard exit at the end of the script didn't change the outcome. My /tmp/ files are fine. I'm checking the timestamps. But I took you're advice and removed them at every run of the script. I added `-v` to the `ssh` command. Still nothing. After creating `/tmp/endofscript`, the script stalls indefinitely.

Comment: @Fritzip Okay, when running `ssh user@remote "/some/command"`, the ssh process will normally exit when the remote ssh server closes the channel which is running the command. And the remote ssh server will close the channel when it sees an EOF on the command's standard output. If the ssh process isn't exiting, it can be because some long-running process on the remote system is holding an open reference to the standard output pipe. This is a long shot, but maybe some command is started in .bashrc or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `-o ServerAliveInterval=60` fixes the issue.

> The ServerAliveInterval option prevents your router from thinking the SSH connection is idle by sending packets over the network between your device and the destination server every 60 seconds.
> ([source](https://medium.com/swlh/keep-ssh-connections-alive-2712462ba68d))

In the case of a script that takes several minutes to execute and that has no output, this will keep the connection alive and avoid it from timing out and being left hanging.

Two options :

- `ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=60 remote@remote "/home/remote/path/to/script.sh"`
- Adding the following lines to `~/.ssh/config` of `local` computer (replace `remote` by the name of your remote or `*` to enable for any remote):

  ```
  Host remote
      ServerAliveInterval 60
  ```

For additional information :

- [What do options `ServerAliveInterval` and `ClientAliveInterval` in sshd_config do exactly?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3026/what-do-options-serveraliveinterval-and-clientaliveinterval-in-sshd-config-d)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `set -xv` in the scripts, or executing both the scripts with `bash -xv script.sh`to get the details of the scripts execution?